# MS Chart: X-AXIS labels repeating

Tags: c#, .net, mschart

I am trying to create multi series line chart using MS Chart. I have created it successfully. But the problem is the x-axis labels repeation. Here is what is created

[image]

Can anyone tell me why the months are repeated? how can i avoid it?
UPDATE:
Here is the code:

```
DateTime[] xvals = {DateTime.Now.AddMonth(-1),DateTime.Now};
decimal[] gvals = {4.3,0};
decimal[] ypvals = {0,0};
decimal[] yvals = {3.5,0};

                        // create the chart
var chart = new Chart();
chart.Size = new Size(600, 250);
chart.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = BorderSkinStyle.Emboss;
chart.BorderlineColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(26, 59, 105);
chart.BorderlineWidth = 3;

var chartArea = new ChartArea();
chartArea.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
//Remove Y-axis grid lines
chartArea.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "MMM";
chartArea.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightGray;
chartArea.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightGray;
chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new Font("Consolas", 8);
chartArea.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = new Font("Consolas", 8);
chart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);

var series = new Series();
series.Name = "Y";
series.Legend = "Y";
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
series.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
series.IsVisibleInLegend = true;
series.Color = Color.Red;
series.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
series.BorderWidth = 2;
chart.Series.Add(series);
// bind the datapoints
chart.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xvals, yvals);


                        var series2 = new Series();
                        series2.Name = "YP";
                        series2.Legend = "YP";
                        series2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                        series2.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
                        series2.IsVisibleInLegend = true;
                        series2.Color = Color.Yellow;
                        series2.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
                        series2.BorderWidth = 2;
                        chart.Series.Add(series2);

                        // bind the datapoints
                        chart.Series[1].Points.DataBindXY(xvals, ypvals);


                        var series3 = new Series();
                        series3.Name = "G";
                        series3.Legend = "GG";
                        series3.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                        series3.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
                        series3.IsVisibleInLegend = true;
                        series3.Color = Color.Blue;
                        series3.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
                        series3.BorderWidth = 2;
                        chart.Series.Add(series3);

                        // bind the datapoints
                        chart.Series[2].Points.DataBindXY(xvals, gvals);



                        // draw!
                        chart.Invalidate();

                        // write out a file
                        chart.SaveImage("D:\\cha.png", ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: What would you expect? You have only one x-value and you don't output more than the month. try to add more x-values, if that's plausible and show also the days!

Comment: there are two x-values . i have also tried four values .. still repeating. @TaW

Comment: Sorry, you are right about the X-Values. I was right about the Label format though. simply change it to `chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd.MMM";` and you will see what is happening!

Comment: Thanks @TaW i got the solution. And your answer give me direction towards it. Thanks again.

Comment: hi is there any way to show only 3.5 at one end or 4.3 at alone . Is there any way to show only y co-ordinate on series label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have got the solution.

I have just converted the

```
series1.XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
series2.XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
series3.XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
```

TO:

```
series1.XValueType = ChartValueType.String;
series2.XValueType = ChartValueType.String;
series3.XValueType = ChartValueType.String;
```

and instead of using dates in the `xAxisValues` array used months name as string.

```
DateTime[] xvals = {DateTime.Now.AddMonth(-1),DateTime.Now};
```

TO:

```
string[] xvals = {DateTime.Now.AddMonth(-1).ToString("MMM"),DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM")};
```

Hope this helps someone else.